# How can I inizialize that ActiveRecord Tableless Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to inizialize an ActiveRecord Tableless Model.

In my model I have:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  # The following ActiveRecord Tableless Model statement is from http://codetunes.com/2008/07/20/tableless-models-in-rails/
  def self.columns() 
    @columns ||= [];
  end

  def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
    columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null)
  end

  attr_reader :id,
              :firstname,
              :lastname,

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @id = attributes[:id]
    @firstname = attributes[:firstname]
    @lastname = attributes[:lastname]
  end
end
```

If in a controller, for example in the application_controller.rb file, I do:

```
@new_account = Account.new({:id => "1", :firstname => "Test name", :lastname => "Test lastname"})
```

a debug\inspect output of the `@new_account` variable is

```
"#<Account >"
```

**Why? How I should inizialize properly that ActiveRecord Tableless Model and make it to work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to that blog post it would have to look like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  class_inheritable_accessor :columns

  def self.columns() 
    @columns ||= [];
  end

  def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
    columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null)
  end

  column :id, :integer
  column :firstname, :string
  column :lastname, :string

end
```

And then:

```
@new_account = Account.new({:id => "1", :firstname => "Test name", :lastname => "Test lastname"})
```

Did you already try it like that?

Comment: it sets all fields other than id.(it is `nil`)

Comment: You are right. I suppose `id` has a special status in ActiveRecord. I think it would only be set after the record is persisted in some database.

Comment: @Wukerplank Your code works, but what about 'attr_reader' and 'attr_writer'? If I try to set more of them, I will have some trouble showing, for example, '@new_account.lastname'. What do you advice about (for security reasons)?

Comment: I've tested it and `@new_account.lastname` does work. By defining :lastname as a column of the model, ActiveRecord generates the getter and setter methods. So `@new_account.firstname = 'Chris'` will work too.

Comment: @Wukerplank If I set just one attribute for 'attr_reader' the '@new_account.<name_attribute>' code works, but if I set more attributes for 'attr_reader' it doesn't work: the output is blank. BTW: is it safe don't care 'attr_accessible' values using a Tableless model or someone maliciuos hacker can change them values?

Comment: Could you update the question with the code you are currently using?

Comment: @Wukerplank Sorry, but now I am interest mainly to retrieve the 'id' that, as @rubyprince said, is 'nil'. It is very important to get that value in my application. P.S.: I will update the question later, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Wukerplank I opened a new question to try to solve the 'id' issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197964/trouble-on-accessing-the-id-value-of-a-tableless-models

Comment: I have factored out the pattern into a seperate class called VirtualRecord detailed here http://xtargets.com/2011/08/02/tableless-views-with-active-record/

Answer (score 0):

I my view, you don't need to extend ActiveRecord::Base class.
You can write your own model class something like this

```
# models/letter.rb
class Letter
  attr_reader :char

  def self.all
    ('A'..'Z').map { |c| new(c) }
  end

  def self.find(param)
    all.detect { |l| l.to_param == param } || raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
  end

  def initialize(char)
    @char = char
  end

  def to_param
    @char.downcase
  end

  def products
    Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", @char + '%'], :order => "name")
  end
end

# letters_controller.rb
def index
  @letters = Letter.all
end

def show
  @letter = Letter.find(params[:id])
end
```

I hope it will help you.
Reference: http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model

Comment: I inherit from < ActiveRecord::Base because I need extend that class so that I can make associations (has_one, belongs_to, ...) with other ActiveRecords in my application. Your code don't support that... thanks, anyway.

Comment: I think he needs sql_connections methods of ActiveRecord in column method.. that may be why he is extending from ActiveRecord.