# Trouble on accessing the id value for a Tableless models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, attributes

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I followed the [Tableless models in Rails](http://codetunes.com/2008/07/20/tableless-models-in-rails/) istructions in order to apply that to a my model Account.

All works, but if I do

```
@test = account.id
```

a debug of `@test` results in a *nil* value and seems not accessible at all.

---

In a comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193246/how-can-i-inizialize-that-activerecord-tableless-model) @Wukerplank said:

```
You are right. I suppose id has a special status in ActiveRecord. I think it would only be set after the record is persisted in some database.
```

---

**How can I retrive\access the id attribute value?**

---

**UPDATED**

Trying and re-trying I discovered that a possible solution is to make all attributes 'attr_accessible' (if I make just the 'id', I get all other value 'nil'), but I think it is a very dangerous solution.

Another solution is to create a new class attribute that acts as the `id`, but why I have to do that if I have already the id?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use ActiveModel instead? Check [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) screencast.

Comment: ActiveModel doesn't support associations